# Gradient fill for nodes with forest package

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

With Tikz, I can specify that my tree nodes use a gradient fill by specifying the top and bottom colours, using something like this:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=aubergine!20}]]
  \node {$a$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to use a similar fill for the nodes in a diagram I have created with the `forest` package.

I can use a solid colour by setting the `fill` option in the `before typesetting nodes` part of the diagram definition but I cannot see a way to specify a gradient fill:

```
\begin{forest}
  before typesetting nodes={for tree={draw, fill=aubergine!20}},
  [A[B]]
\end{forest}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any problem using `top color` and `bottom color`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  before typesetting nodes={for tree={draw, top color=red!20, bottom color=red!80}},
  [A[B]]
\end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't think to try that, but in hindsight I guess it was slightly obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamWilliams You don't need `before typesetting nodes` here. Just `for tree={...}` will do. (This will be slightly quicker.)